# Why do the threads initiate slowly?

Tags: python

It takes about 15 minutes for about 300 threads to initiate (prints out: 'initiated with proxy'); however, whenever I remove all the code within the while loop in the threads' run function, it initiates all threads within 10 seconds (maybe less). Any ideas as to what in the while loop is making all the threads initiate/start extremely slowly?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests
import sys
import string
import os.path
import urllib.request
import threading
import mimetypes
from time import gmtime, strftime, sleep
from random import choice

#list of our proxies
proxies = []
working = []

downloads = 1
initiated = 0

#the number of files we want to download
target = int(sys.argv[1])

#argument 2 - proxies
try:
    sys.argv[2]
except:
    pass
else:
    param = sys.argv[2]

    if param.find('.txt') != -1:
        print('Loading specified proxy list ('+ param +').')

        f = open(param, 'r+')
        print('Opening '+ f.name)
        proxylist = f.read()
        f.close()

        #split retrieved list by new line
        proxies = proxylist.split('\n')
    else:
        print('Single proxy specified.')
        proxies.append(param)


class thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ID, name, proxy):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.id = ID
        self.name = name
        self.downloads = 0
        self.proxy = proxy
        self.running = True
        self.fails = 0
    def run(self):
        global downloads
        global working
        global initiated

        initiated += 1

        if self.proxy != False:
            #id is always above one, so make the ID -1
            self.proxy = proxies[(self.id-1)]

            print(self.name +' initiating with proxy: '+self.proxy)
        else:
            print(self.name +' initiating without a proxy.')

        #start actual downloads
        while downloads <= target and self.running:
            #wait for all threads to be loaded before starting requests
            if (initiated-1) == len(proxies):
                rstr = ''.join(choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for x in range(5))

                url = 'http://puu.sh/'+rstr
                filename = 'downloaded/'+ strftime('%Y %m %d %H-%M-%S ['+ rstr +']', gmtime()) +'.png'

                try:
                    if self.proxy != False:
                        #make our requests go through proxy
                        r = requests.get(url, None, {'http' : self.proxy})
                    else:
                        r = requests.get(url)
                except IOError:
                    if self.fails >= 10:
                        #print(self.name +': Proxy is not working. Stopping thread.')
                        self.running = False

                    self.fails += 1
                    pass
                except:
                    pass
                else:

                    if r.status_code == 200 and r.headers['Content-Type'] != 'text/html':
                        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                            for chunk in r.iter_content(1024):
                                f.write(chunk)

                        print(self.name +': '+ filename+' downloaded...' + str(downloads))

                        downloads += 1
                        self.downloads += 1

                        if not self.proxy in working and self.proxy != False:
                                working.append(self.proxy)

                        sleep(5)


#lets create the "downloaded" folder if it does not exist
if not os.path.isdir('downloaded'):
    try:
        os.mkdir('downloaded')
    except:
        pass

#thread count
thread_count = 1

#create threads, and initiate them
try:
    thread(0, 'Thread-main', False).start()

    for x in proxies:
        thread(thread_count, 'Thread-'+str(thread_count), proxies[(thread_count-1)]).start()
        thread_count += 1
except:
    print('Couldn\'t start threads.')
```

Comment: Why on earth would you want to spawn 300 threads (especially in Python, with the GIL and everything)? For this kind of stuff async IO is much better (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962808/asynchronous-http-calls-in-python).

Comment: Python sucks at threading. Anyway: you might want to first allocate all threads (put them in an array) and then call `.start()` on them. Will spawn them a lot faster.

Comment: @MatteoItalia What other choice do I have? I'm not sure if I should go multiprocessing.

Comment: @Justin Do it in one thread, using async IO.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I completely agrees with Matteo Italia's comment. I also think that you have a problem with the usage of the variable `initiated`:

Your code looks like:

```
   while downloads <= target and self.running:
        #wait for all threads to be loaded before starting requests
        if (initiated-1) == len(proxies):
            ...
        # nothing in else
```

therefore all the thread are waiting actively ! Which means they are using a lot of CPU just waiting for the other threads... You should block on an event:

```
initiated = 0
all_ready = Event()
```

and in `run()`:

```
if initiated-1 == len(proxies):
    all_ready.set()
else:
    all_ready.wait()
while downloads <= target and self.running:
    ...
```

Comment: Could you just print ``initiated`` before the if and see if it grows up as expected. By the way, I don't understand why ``-1`` in ``initiated-1``.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are running each thread sequentially - you create each thread, then you start it, then it starts, it prints out the message, then it goes and does all that web stuff, then it sleeps, then during that sleep the next thread can be started, if instead another already created thread isn't scheduled.

Of course, as mentioned, python is pretty terrible at threading. Try to avoid it.

Comment: So what should I do? Use another language for this or find an alternative method?